# 2 C++ constructor errors, "explicit type is missing - line 13" and "no instance of constructor = line 24"

Tags: c++, constructor

I am learning oop in c++. I made a class named `Ytchannel`, added some variables and a constructor. For some reason, visual studio code is not recognizing the constructor as a constructor and saying that it needs a return type like `void` etc. When I try to call the constructor in the main function, it says that I don't have a constructor in my class when I clearly do. Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Ytchannel {
public:
    int subscribers;
    string ownerName;
    string creationDate;
    string channelName;

    Chan(string ownerNam, string creationDat, string channelNam, int subscriber) {
        ownerName = ownerNam;
        creationDate = creationDat;
        subscribers = subscriber;
        channelName = channelNam;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Ytchannel sin("Sam", "7/4/2020", "SamSmees", 1029);
}
```

Comment: Your constructor needs to be named like the class. (Ytchannel != Chan) Whenever you find yourself saying something like "...which I clearly have", double-check. The compiler is *very* seldom wrong.

Comment: Your class does *not* have a constructor. A constructor is a function with the same name as the class it is in .